# ComboBox template problems in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox, datatemplate

I have a listview with a DataTemplate that has a ComboBox. I want the ComboBox to look flat like a label until the user actually wants to change the value. I had the example below working before, but I changed things around a bit, and now it doesn't work anymore and I'm not sure why.

The IsMouseOver property does not seem to be working correctly, as it only gets set when the mouse is right at the border of the control.

What can I do to make this work correctly?

Here is a snippet:

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AccountCategories" />

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="FlatCombo" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <ContentControl
            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"

            Margin="4,3,3,3" 
            />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="DropDown">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="False" />            
        <Style.Triggers> 
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />                       
                    <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FlatCombo}" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Category">
        <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" Style="{StaticResource DropDown}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource db}, Path=Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Category}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>


    <ListView Margin="0,110,0,0" Name="lstCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AccountCategories}}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Category" Width="100"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource Category}" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Balance}" Header="Balance" Width="100" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the code you provided, supplied some data for the collections, and it worked just like you wanted it to.  I would suggest using [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) to look to see if there are any other elements consuming the events you expect the ListView to handle.

Comment: Hah, turns out it was a label at the top of the window. The height was going all the way down the window, covering most of that column in the ListBox.

Comment: Can someone post the supporting classes for this example?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when your are having issues with Mouse events firing correctly it's due to the background missing. If the element you expect to receive events has a null reference for a background, the control will not receive the events; only the control underneath of it will. Try setting the background of your ContentControl to "Transparent". That should fix your problem.

Comment: Nope, looks like that's not doing anything. If I change to a Button, still the same.

It's acting like there's something invisible in front of it; when I try clicking, it doesn't even select the ListViewItem.